# Eclipse IDE error : Server has been stopped during publish process

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hana

I installed Eclipse IDE JAVA EE edition and all other required plugins. I have created server instance(WEB JAVA)and pointed it to local directory C:\dev\hanacloud.sdk\xyz using default settings.

I ran project  by selecting(It contains pom file) `project(ESCMP-web) ->RUN AS -> RUN ON SERVER ->choose an existing server -> Web JAVA -> finish`  , after few seconds it gives an error message as

> 'Publishing to Java Web Server...' has encountered a problem.
>
> Publish failed: Server has been stopped during publish process.
>
> [image: error]

Console message :

```
 java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
C:\dev\eclipse\workspace\Servers\Java Web Server-config>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java" -server  "-Dhttp.proxyHost=172.30.0.14" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128" "-Dhttps.proxyHost=172.30.0.14" "-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128" "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.corp|localhost|127.0.0.1" "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"  -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar  -console -dev "file:C:/dev/eclipse/workspace/Servers/Java Web Server-config/configuration/dev.properties" 
osgi> Updating file with path [C:\dev\eclipse\workspace\Servers\Java Web Server-config\.\pickup\espm-mobile-shopping-web.war]

Update of file with path [C:\dev\eclipse\workspace\Servers\Java Web Server-config\.\pickup\espm-mobile-shopping-web.war] is successful.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.


log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\dev\eclipse\workspace\Servers\Java Web Server-config\configuration\1419836491312.log.
```

Server log file for session:

```
!SESSION 2014-12-29 12:31:30.984 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -console -dev file:C:/dev/eclipse/workspace/Servers/Java Web Server-config/configuration/dev.properties

!ENTRY com.sap.conn.jco.cloud 4 0 2014-12-29 12:31:34.250
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.sap.conn.jco.NeoActivator.start() of bundle com.sap.conn.jco.cloud.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load the JCo native library. (exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path)
If you don't develop a JCo scenario for HANA Cloud, you can ignore this issue.
Check if you have installed the Visual Studio 2010 runtime libraries in the correct version. (vcredist.msi)
The 64bit msi can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632

    at com.sap.conn.jco.NeoActivator.processLoadError(NeoActivator.java:73)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.NeoActivator.start(NeoActivator.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load the JCo native library. (exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path)
If you don't develop a JCo scenario for HANA Cloud, you can ignore this issue.
Check if you have installed the Visual Studio 2010 runtime libraries in the correct version. (vcredist.msi)
The 64bit msi can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14632

    at com.sap.conn.jco.NeoActivator.processLoadError(NeoActivator.java:73)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.NeoActivator.start(NeoActivator.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.007
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.007
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/com.sap.conn.jco.cloud.win32.x86_64_3.1.1.9.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.sap.conn.jco.cloud.win32.x86_64 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.007
!MESSAGE Missing host null_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.367
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.367
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/com.sap.conn.jco.cloud.win32.x86_64_3.1.1.9.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.sap.conn.jco.cloud.win32.x86_64 2 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.367
!MESSAGE Missing host null_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-12-29 12:32:04.367
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Other information:

Server: neo-java-web-sdk-1.58.18.1 downloaded from [SAP TOOL](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#cloud)
Eclipse: JAVA EE IDE LUNA-4.4. 
Sysetm: Windows-8.1 pro 64 bit 
JDK : JDk-1.7.71

How to resolve this error ?

Edit:

**Sometime error doesn't occur .** I have no idea why it's happening even though visual studio 2010 run time library  x64 is installed .

Comment: `If you don't develop a JCo scenario for HANA Cloud, you can ignore this issue.` Do you develop a JCO scenario? The error is thrown by eclipse (see `org.eclipse.osgi.framework...`), can you try to run your server outside Eclipse?